# Template route not generating correct URLs

Tags: template-routes

I followed [Boyink's tutorial](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/introduction-to-template-routes-for-expressionengine) to the letter but still can't get template routes to work.

My multi-entry template is located at `company/people`. My single entry template is at company/person.

In the Template Route manager, I have `/company/people/{bio:alpha_dash}` for the `company/person template.

Multi-entry template link code:

```
<a href="{route="company/people" bio="{url_title}"}">
```

Single-entry template channel entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="people"
    limit="1"
    require_entry="yes"
    dynamic="no"
    url_title="{segment:bio}"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
```

All of the links in the multi-entry template look like: `/company/%7Broute=`

I don't understand why the URL's are not getting generated correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the routes on [Route Manager](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_route_manager.html)?

Comment: Yes. In the Template Route manager, I have /company/people/{bio:alpha_dash} for the company/person template.

Comment: `/company/%7Broute=` translates as `/company/{route=`. Is `/company/%7Broute=` the full generated URL?

Comment: Yes. That is all that is being generated.

Comment: I can't think on anything else than a syntax error. It looks like some `"` or `}` is missing somewhere. For now, you can use a root relative link: `<a href="/company/people/{url_title}">`.

Comment: That works. I wonder if this is some sort of EE bug?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25212/discussion-between-robson-sobral-and-mediapimp).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think on anything else than a syntax error. For now, you can use a root relative link:

```
<a href="/company/people/{url_title}">
```

It looks like some `"` or `}` is missing somewhere. Maybe some javascript? Or some CSS rule? Try to look for them or to replace the `"` by `'` inside the `{route}`:

```
<a href="{route='company/people' bio='{url_title}'}">
```

You can also, use the good old `{url_title_path}`:

```
<a href="{url_title_path='company/people'}">
```